# simple_query_string in elasticsearch is giving value even if no record with such value exsist

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

In the below query of elasticsearch which i am executing using kibana, it is giving all the records but none of the record contains the value 8659355 inside it

```
GET /My_test_Index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "8659355"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the below query also it is giving all the values

```
GET /My_test_Index/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "372034"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

the above query give the explanation of

```
   "_explanation" : {
          "value" : 1.0,
          "description" : "sum of:",
          "details" : [
            {
              "value" : 1.0,
              "description" : "sum of:",
              "details" : [
                {
                  "value" : 1.0,
                  "description" : "BinaryDocValuesRangeQuery(fieldName=,from=37.2034,to=37.2034)",
                  "details" : [ ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value" : 0.0,
              "description" : "match on required clause, product of:",
              "details" : [
                {
                  "value" : 0.0,
                  "description" : "# clause",
                  "details" : [ ]
                },
                {
                  "value" : 1.0,
                  "description" : "DocValuesFieldExistsQuery [field=_primary_term]",
                  "details" : [ ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

i have no clue to get this solved

Comment: Can you add `"size": 1, "explain": true` to your query and update your question with the results you get or share it via gist?

Comment: after adding this to my query 

```

I am getting below response {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[simple_query_string] unsupported field [size]",
        "line": 8,
        "col": 21
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[simple_query_string] unsupported field [size]",
    "line": 8,
    "col": 21
  },
  "status": 400
}

Comment: You need to add that at the top level of your query, above `"query"`

Comment: still its giving all the values

Comment: Yes, but please read my above comment fully

Comment: @val i have updated the query as you said, the results are same

Comment: ...and **update** your question **with the results** you get (not the query!!) or share it via gist?

Comment: @val i have updated the question with the response

Comment: Do you mind sharing the full output via gist?

Comment: @Val what is gist?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ or any other similar service for sharing large files